# How do I get the GRUB menu to show when starting my dual-boot system?

Tags: grub2

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 and selected a wrong option while installing it.

Now the problem is that my machine directly boots Ubuntu and even does not show me grub menu.

How do I install grub menu ?

And how do I add Windows Vista to the grub menu?

This is what I have tried.

```
sudo grub

> root (hd0,0)

> setup (hd0)

Error 17: Cannot mount selected partition
```

I don't know what's going wrong here and I am sure that I have not wiped out my windows partition.

**Edit :**

```
sudo update-grub

Generating grub.cfg ...  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic  
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin  
ls: cannot access /media/BC54B2C654B282A6/boot  
Boot: No such file or directory  
done
```

---

```
sudo os-prober

ls: cannot access /media/BC54B2C654B282A6/boot  
Boot: No such file or directory
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update - investigating what os-prober should do. Please add what devices have which system installed (e.g. /dev/sda1 Ubuntu; /dev/sda4 Windows). If you are not booting from removable media, (USB drive, etc.) remove it as the /media/BC5... entry seems to be gumming up the works.

Comment: @msw I am trying to run this command form installed ubuntu and I have removed all removable media. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it definitely looks like grub is looking for some external media.Did you mount /boot on a separate partition?

Comment: @tinhed I have used my linux partition as / (root) while formating.

Comment: I see that it tries to access `/media/BC54B2C654B282A6/boot` a directory that no windows have. Please, include all the scripts under `/etc/grub.d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using `sudo update-grub` and `sudo os-prober` but I had no luck.

So this is what I have done.

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and placed a comment # in front of the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Then I updated my grub so that I don't have to press Left shift for the grub to appear using `sudo update-grub` .

After updating the grub I opened grub.cfg using `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` command.

And added

```
menuentry "Windows Vista" {

set root='(hd0,1)'

chainloader +1

}
```

between `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###` and `### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###`

And don't forget to save the file.

I am marking this answer as Community wiki in case someone wants to add or modify this post.

---

Edit to update:

Meanwhile (2013) we have a GUI tool to repair/reinstall grub: **Boot Repair**.

To use it, do one of the following:

- Create a live CD/USB of [Ubuntu Secure Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix), which is an Ubuntu live with supplementary rescue tools, boot from that and use **Boot Repair**.
- If you already have a regular Ubuntu live iso, create live usb  with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), live boot from that and install Boot Repair

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
>   update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair &

(But `apt-get update` on a live USB might involve updates that take some time - and are also useless if the live usb is not persistent - so I recommend the first solution.)

Using **Boot Repair** to fix/reinstall GRUB is simple, just choose default/recommended repair option; more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 3):

The first part is that the GRUB menu is there it just hides but the left-shift key during boot brings it up (as described in [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time-on-a-single-boot-system-not-dual-boot) (obvious, no?)).

The second part is that `update-grub` should run `os-prober` and find your Windows boot and chain-load it. The output of update-grub would be helpful in figuring out what isn't happening correctly.

Comment: I have added update-grub output. Please help.