# After Apple upgrade I'm unable to boot into my ubuntu 13.10 via refit partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, refit

I'm currently running Ubuntu 13.10 on a minimac through a refit partition (500gb mac - 1.5 tb linux). Today I took an apple upgrade to OSX Maverick which was fine and when I tried to boot back into Linux, the refit screen opened, offering me apple or ubuntu. I selected ubuntu and got 'No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the upgrade has either removed GRUB from the MBR or adjusted the [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) on your disk. Three possible solutions spring immediately to mind:

- Install my [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) in place of rEFIt, along with an EFI filesystem driver for whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel. This will enable you to boot Linux more directly (via an option whose name includes the string `vmlinuz`), bypassing GRUB and obviating the need for a hybrid MBR.
- Repair your hybrid MBR. My [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) program (part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu, IIRC) offers the most flexible options for doing this, but the `gptsync` program that comes with both rEFIt and rEFInd is easier to use. (Note that rEFInd's `gptsync` is an updated version that will probably produce a slightly different hybrid MBR than what rEFIt's `gptsync` produces.)
- Re-install GRUB. You can do this [manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16167/installing-grub) or by using the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) program using an Ubuntu live CD. It's probably best to do this *after* generating a new hybrid MBR, unless you're certain that your hybrid MBR is still valid.

Comment: Same error message: "no bootable device.. ", I follow the first solution to install refind with ./install --esp, installation was sucessful but, the same error message appears after I choose linux from refind: "no bootable device". I enter partition tool, and it showed: no gptsync.efi was found.