# Set Ubuntu partition back to active and boot with Chameleon

Tags: 13.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

I recently installed OS X (Hackintosh) on my PC on a partion, alongside Windows and Ubuntu. After some try with settings bootloader and other, my Ubuntu partition is no more active. Grub has been replaced with a non-working bootloader, so I restored Windows default bootloader.

So now, I have 3 OSes on my PC, but when PC turns on just windows starts.
If I previously load an external bootloader I can boot OS X but there's no way to run Ubuntu.

**Although this question seems to be related more on Chameleon the main question is: How can I set back the partition of Ubuntu to active (seen that it is the only OS I can no more boot) and how can I run it alongside OS X and Windows (possibly using Chameleon, but I wouldn't dislike using of other bootloaders)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you need to re-install GRUB to your hard disk's MBR. (Chameleon has probably replaced GRUB.) [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can probably do this, or you can [install GRUB manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16167/installing-grub) (this requires that you be able to boot Linux, but a live CD should be OK, albeit perhaps with some changes to the procedure).

Comment: I'm going to try it, but after I reinstall grub can you tell me then how can I boot OS X (if I'm not going too much off topic - but this is an intricate question so why not ask -)?

Comment: GRUB should be able to chainload to Chameleon's second stage in the OS X partition. You might need to create a manual stanza for this, though. Alternatively, GRUB can boot OS X directly, although this is pretty delicate to set up, and well outside the scope of this site. Asking on a Hackintosh forum will likely get you better responses. Also and FWIW, complex triple-boot setups on BIOS computers are often helped immensely by having two hard disks; that way, each one can have its own MBR-based boot loader, reducing conflicts.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. I used BootRepair all the time: Here's what I did: I ran Ubuntu Live on USB and downloaded Boot-Repair (I saw a guide on what it does exactly and how use it). I made at first automatic repair to set back Ubuntu as active. Then I went back to hackintosh and installed a custom bootloader (I used Enoch, branch of Chameleon). Then I set OSX as first partition to run with BootRepair and it showed finally all the 3 OSes. In the end I ran Windows Repair CD (boot manager broken) to repair MBR files, and ran for the last time BootRepair to set back OSX partition as first.