# How to dual boot OSX and Ubuntu without having to delete and reinstall Ubuntu in a Dell laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, system-installation

I am trying to install OSX Lion on my Dell studio with Ubuntu being the current and only operating system.  Is there a way to dual boot without having to delete and reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a solution there is. I made a similar question on this site here:
[Set Ubuntu partition back to active and boot with Chameleon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379564/set-ubuntu-partition-back-to-active-and-boot-with-chameleon)

The difference is that I've done a triple boot, not dual, which is harder on just a HDD. This is what you have to do.

1. Prepare your OS X DVD (prepared with Unibeast or something like which works on PCs, a DVD is always preferable than a USB for further bootloaders issues)
2. On Ubuntu, make a partition to your drive of the space you want OS X to be and format it as FAT32 (it will be changed after, but in this way the installer finds it)
3. Boot your OS X DVD and install it on the partition (formatted as Journaled, but you can find these things in guides)
4. After you installed all the drivers, install the bootloader which will replace the GRUB (I used Enoch)
5. If you are not able to see Ubuntu at start of PC in the list of OSes, run Ubuntu Live CD, install BootRepair and set back Ubuntu as active partition, then set the partition of Mac OSX to run as first.
6. If everything goes well, you will be able to dual boot at start. (Remember that you can custom your bootloader preferences from an app, for example it at defaults runs OSX in 2 seconds if you don't press F8 key, while I chose to show immediately the OS list.

This thing is easier for you than how much it was for me, since Windows, Ubuntu and OS X use 3 different bootloaders and I installed them on the same HDD.

EDIT Notes:
Always keep these 2 things post-installation, you may always need them.
- An external OSX bootloader, if you have troubles with Enoch or Chameleon on HDD, you can always boot with DVD until you solve your issues (like I did)
- A Ubuntu Live CD for using BootRepair to solve issues you do or change partition priority to run.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: You can't install OSX in a non-Apple system. It just doesn't work.

> Apple systems check for a specific chip and refuse to run or install without it - this is called the [system management controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller), and in effect is a glorified fan controller amongst other things.

Of course, there is a workaround for everything but that doesn't mean that you wouldn't have another piece of hardware that doesn't work or behaves strangely.

Apart the fact that the installation may nuke your boot loader and/or Ubuntu partition.

Reference:

- https://superuser.com/a/679911/235569

Comment: All - please do not "discuss" this answer in comments.  Remember we validate answers via your voting power - up or down.  If you wish to discuss further, create a Meta question.  Thanks.